DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly not Providing Unauth User Read Access
While using the DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly as Permission for my CBV, for unauth user, Ready only methods should work. But i'm not able to fetch the data.
First I taught its behaviour must got have changes from rest_framework, so Checked the Documentation also. There it is mentioned - "Similar to DjangoModelPermissions, but also allows unauthenticated users to have read-only access to the API."
